# Unrolling gcc compiler optimization

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

I am interested in seeing the code where gcc has actually optimized the code. Is there a way I could do?

I have gone through few other similar questoins, I have tried following few things,

1. -Wa,ahl=filename.lst :- this option is really good, you can browse the code and corresponding machine code, but it is not good when I enable O3 option.
2. Dumping optimized tree :- I am sure gcc is giving me good amount of debug information. But I do not how to decipher it. I will be glad if someone could point to any available information.

Is there any other better way, to find out what part of the code gcc optimized?

Thanks,
Madhur

Comment: Have you tried gcc -O3 -S myFile1.c? The output file will be the optimized assembly file myFile1.s. To see the optimizations, it's best to read the assembly code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can compile the code twice, first with:

```
$ gcc -O0 -S -o yourfile_o0.s
```

Then with:

```
$ gcc -O3 -S -o yourfile_o3.s
```

Then you can `diff` the two resulting assembly files:

```
$ diff -u yourfile_o0.s yourfile_o3.s
$ vim -d yourfile_o0.s yourfile_o3.s
$ emacs --eval '(ediff "yourfile_o0.s" "yourfile_o3.s")'
```

Comment: +1, It's how I've done in the past during my more curious moments :-)

Comment: Would you mind putting each command on a different line? I think it will better for reading. :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the assember code or decompile your compiled application. C decompilers produce ugly C code, but for analyzing which code was generated, it have to suffice.